# How to populate table view with large data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to populate a table view with a large data. However, my tableview can only display 20 string objects. How do I simply display the rest of the data and update the table view each time the user scrolls to the end?

```
var people = [People]()
let configureSession = URLSessionConfiguration.default


    let session = URLSession(configuration: configure)

    //Setup the Api Key...
    let apiKey = "https://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/legislators?apikey=(//Api Key here...)"

if error != nil{
                print("ERROR: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                return
            } else if let jsonData = data {
                do{
                    let parsedJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
                    guard let results = parsedJSON["results"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {return}
                    for result in results{
                        let name = myClass()
name.firstName = result["first_name"] as! String
self.people.append(name)
}
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        //Reload the data
                        self.table.reloadData()
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError{
                    print(error)
                }
            }
}).resume()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return people.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = people[indexPath.row] //Only displays 20... Need to display more!

    return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    //Code to display the rest of the data goes here?

}
```

Comment: what you mean large data  dont understand

Comment: it will display all the [array count]

Comment: simple answer, just tell `UITableView` how many items to be displayed, and how they will be displayed through `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`. Let the System handle the rest.

Comment: It's great to start with this http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/

Comment: Post your code for `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: Not related, but **never** create a reused cell in `willDisplayCell`. The affected cell is passed in the `cell` parameter.

Comment: And only set things like fonts, color, checkmarks, etc in `willDisplayCell`. All data should be added in `cellForRowAt`

Comment: You need to learn basics of TableView. You don't need to care about how to display data when user scrolls. You just pass the tableview delegates the data you need to display (typically NSMutableArray) and leave it everything to the iOS to handle it.

Comment: @Rocotilos i updated the code so you could see exactly what the problem is. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: There is no problem. I think your code is ok now. Just delete the willDisplayCell delegate. You don't need that unless you want to change the display of the cell before it loads (like cell background color). As for why your table only show 20 data that is because your people array only has 20 data. Add more to your people array and reload table to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you return the correct value in `numberOfRowsInSection` method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myLargeData.count
}
```

With provided `myLargeData` array there should be 30 rows in your tableView

Answer (score -1):

You can use number of rows in section delegate of table view delegate to handle the more data in array.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{
    return yourarray.count
}
```